# Receiving didReceiveMemoryWarning on loading a 3D model using ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to load a 3D model which is of huge size using ARKit- Scenekit. Every time I try to place the object, the app is being killed automatically with memory warning.I am following the ARKit Placing objects sample to place my model.

How to deal with memory warnings in ARKit? I also cleared all the caches in didReceiveMemoryWarning by using the below code but still no luck,

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
    URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
    print("didReceiveMemoryWarning")
    self.showAlert(errorTitle: "Alert", errorMessage: "Terminating app due to memory issue")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "huge size"?  Can you provide some numbers?  How many polygons are we talking about?  How many textures?  What are the texture sizes (MB, dimensions etc.)?

Comment: I would hazard a guess it has something to do with the size of your textures... try to compress them and see if that helps...

Comment: The .scn file is close to 490 MB. I know it is of huge size but we are just trying to test this for a demo. The total texture files size is close to 95 MB.

Comment: @JoshRobbins How do we compress the textures? Some of the texture file format is of .tga type.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual SCN file...

Comment: I am sorry but thats a purchased model and I cannot share it without proper approval. Can you please let me know what details I should give you to solve this issue? I will try to get the details that you are looking for.  In general, will ARKit support models that are of huge size?

Comment: @yaali are there any updates on your problem? I am currently facing the same issue and would really appreciate any solution.

Comment: @junxi No after struggling a lot, I replaced the original dae file with a newer one that has lower polygons and file size to eliminate the memory issue